# Dynamic Repository With Dynamic Methods

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Inspired by this post [dynamic-repositories-in-lightspeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2011/04/26/dynamic-repositories-in-lightspeed/) I am trying to build my own like this.

I have a abstract `GenericRepository` like this. I have omitted most of the code for simplicity (Its just normal Add/Update/Filtering methods).

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<TEntity, TContext> : 
        DynamicObject, 
        IDataRepository<TEntity>
           where TEntity : class, new()
           where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
        protected TContext context;
        protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
}
```

As you can see, my abstract `GenericRepository` extends from `DynamicObject` to support dynamic repositories.

I also have a abstract UnitOfWork implementation which generated a repository for a given entity at runtime like this. Again, base classes and other details are irrelevant for the question, but I'm happy to provide them if you require.

```
public abstract class UnitOfWorkBase<TContext> : IUnitOfWork
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
   public abstract IDataRepository<T> Repository<T>() 
      where T : class, IIdentifiableEntity, new();

   // Code
}
```

Following class implements abstract method of the above class.

```
public class MyUnitOfWorkBase : UnitOfWorkBase<MyDataContext>
    {
        public override IDataRepository<T> Repository<T>()
        {
            if (Repositories == null)
                Repositories = new Hashtable();

            var type = typeof(T).Name;

            if (!Repositories.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                var repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepositoryImpl<,>);
                var genericType = repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T), typeof(InTeleBillContext));
                var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

                Repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
            }

            return (IDataRepository<T>)Repositories[type];
        }
    }
```

Now, whenever I want to create a dynamic repository for basic CRUD functions, I can do it like this.

```
    var uow = new MyUnitOfWorkBase();
    var settingsRepo = uow.Repository<Settings>(); 
    var settingsList = settingsRepo.Get().ToList();
```

Now, What I want to do is something like this.

```
dynamic settingsRepo = uow.Repository<Settings>();
var result = settingsRepo.FindSettingsByCustomerNumber(774278L);
```

Here, `FindSettingsByCustomerNumber()` is a dynamic method. I resolve this method using this code.

```
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<TEntity, TContext> :
        GenericRepository<TEntity, TContext>
        where TEntity : class, IIdentifiableEntity, new()
        where TContext : DbContext, new()
    { 
        public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, 
                                             object[] args, out object result)
        {
            // Crude parsing for simplicity
            if (binder.Name.StartsWith("Find"))
            {
                int byIndex = binder.Name.IndexOf("By");
                if (byIndex >= 0)
                {
                    string collectionName = binder.Name.Substring(4, byIndex - 4);  
                    string[] attributes = binder.Name.Substring(byIndex + 2)
                                          .Split(new[] { "And" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    var items = DbSet.ToList();

                    Func<TEntity, bool> predicate = entity => entity.GetType().GetProperty(attributes[0]).GetValue(entity).Equals(args[0]);

                    result = items.Where(predicate).ToList();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
        }
    }
```

This is the problem I am having.

using this line `var items = DbSet.ToList();` works well, but if I were to query a large table with 1000's of data, then performance issues occur.

If I directly try to use the `IQueryble` interface and call it like this

Func predicate = entity => entity.GetType().GetProperty(attributes[0]).GetValue(entity).Equals(args[0]);

```
                result = DbSet.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

It gives me an error saying there is no method GetProperty() in LINQ to Entities.

**Is it possible to make it work using LINQ to Entities?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that LINQ-to-Entities needs to convert your expression (given by the predicate) into a SQL query. `entity` is replaced by the database column. Additionally LINQ2Entities supports various expressions (e.g. EqualExpression, etc.). However it cannot support the whole .NET Framework. Especially: what should GetType() on a database column return?

Therefore you need to use the Expresson API to generate the predicate and use only expressions supported by LINQ2Entities. For example: Use a `MemberAccess` expression for accessing a property (LINQ2Entities is able to map that to an SQL query).

Hint: we are doing predicate generation for Entity Framework and had to overcome some additional problems which we could solve using the library `LinqKit`.

If you do not know about the .NET Expression API yet, you need to gather skills in that area before you can resume your dynamic repository idea.

BTW: I don't think that it is a very good idea to have this kind of automatic calls. They are not refactoring safe (i.e. what if you rename the DB column? All your method calls run into problems, and it is not detectable by the compiler).

I would use it only to generate predicates for Where() clauses from Filter-like DTO types.

Answer (score 1):

Unusual pattern - dynamic methods on a repository patterns.But that is another topic.

Dynamic invocation of the repository you have.
So now you need to understand Linq to Entities a little more.

[Linq to Entities language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what you can do with linq to Entities.
Given the expression tree has to be converted in to DB instructions,
it isnt surprising there are restrictions.
In case you are interested [The EF provider specs and links to samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789835%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So given you want to Dynamic EF, you have a few options.
I concentrate on dynamic wheres, but you can apply to other EF methods.

Check out

- [Dynamic Linq on codeplex](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)
  which allows things like

  `public virtual IQueryable<TPoco> DynamicWhere(string predicate, params object[] values) {
          return Context.Set<TPoco>().Where(predicate, values);
      }`

  This Where is an  IQueryable extension that accepts strings...
  [Samples of using this string based predicate parser](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)
- [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)  or even PM> `Install-Package LinqKit`

  Linqkit takes dynamic EF to the next level,
  Offers amazing features like
  `public IQueryable<TPoco> AsExpandable() {
          return Context.Set<TPoco>().AsExpandable();
      }`

  which allows you build AND and ORs progressively.
- [Expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)

  Expression Building API is the most powerful tool to support you here .
  Learning the API is hard. using the tool harder.
  eg Dealing with concatenation very hard.  BUT if you can understand the API and how expressions work.
  It is possible.
  Here is a SIMPLE example. (imagine something complex)

  ```
  public static Expression<Func<TPoco, bool>> GetContainsPredicate<TPoco>(string propertyName,
                                                                          string containsValue)
  {
      // (tpoco t) => t.propertyName.Contains(value ) is built
      var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TPoco), @"t");
      var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
      MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod(@"Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
      var someValue = Expression.Constant(containsValue, typeof(string));
      var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

      return Expression.Lambda<Func<TPoco, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp);
  }
  ```